# django testing without email backend

Tags: python, django, email, testing

I want to test a view in my Django application. So I open the python shell by typing `python` and then I type `from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment`. It seems to work fine. Then I type `setup_test_environment()` and it says

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   EMAIL_BACKEND, but settings are not configured. You must either define
>   the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I don't need to send mails in my test, so why does Django wants me to configure an email back-end ?

Are we forced to configure an email back-end for any test even if it doesn't need it ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting (it has a default), but you do need to define a setting module. You can set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your shell environment, or set `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` to point to your settings module.

Note that calling `python manage.py shell` will set up the Django environment for you, which includes setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and calling `django.setup()`. You still need to call `setup_test_environment()` to manually run tests in your python shell.